# Cannot access to use information from session in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want access user information in from request in my site but when I use this code it shows me this error :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
> (node:10099) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
>
> at Courseontroller.StoreProcess (/home/mrcoder/Projects/Nodejs/Store/app/http/controller/CourseController.js:28:28)
> at Courseontroller.CourseProcess (/home/mrcoder/Projects/Nodejs/Store/app/http/controller/CourseController.js:18:31)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> (node:10099) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
> (node:10099) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I show my setting for the session and log in to find a problem .

This is session setting :

```
     app.use(session({
        secret : 'mysecretkey',
        resave : true,
        saveUninitialized : true,
        cookie : {  expires : new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6)},
        store : new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection : mongoos.connection })
    }));
    app.use(cookieParser('mysecretkey'));
```

This is login local passport :

```
 passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    UserModel.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});


    passport.use('local.login', new localStrategy({
    usernameField: 'phoneNumber',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, phoneNumber, password, done) => {
    UserModel.findOne({ 'phoneNumber': phoneNumber }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return done(err)
        if (!user || !user.ValidationPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('errors', 'کاربری با این مشخصاتا در سیستم ثبت نشده است'));
        }
        return done(null, user);
    })
}))
```

and use in the login controller :

```
    class LoginController extends BaseController {

    Index(req, res) {
        res.render('auth/login');
    }

    async LoginProcess(req, res, next) {

        var result = await this.formValidation(req, res);
        if (result) {
           return await this.Login(req, res, next)
        }
        return res.redirect('/auth/login');
    }


   async Login(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local.login', (err, user) => {
            if (!user) return res.redirect('/auth/login')
            req.logIn(user,function(err) {
                if (err) console.log(err)
                if (req.body.rememberMe) {
                    user.SetRememberToken(res)
                }
                return res.redirect('/admin/dashbaord');
            })
        })(req, res, next)
    }


}

module.exports = new LoginController();
```

Now when I need to use the user information it show me that error. For example I need to use userId for add new  post but it show me that error :

```
async StoreProcess(req, res, next) {
    let images = req.body.images;
    let { title, body, type, price, tags } = req.body;
    console.log(req.user)
    let newCourse = new Course({
        user: req.user._id,
        title,
        slug: this.slug(title),
        body,
        type,
        price,
        images,
        tags
    });
```

What's the problem ? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: maybe it's `req.user.id` instead of `req.user._id` where you do the `new Course`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't have a req.user. I see that you have a typo in your serialize function. As you use MongoDB, it should be:

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);   // _id instead of id
});
```

If you serialize with a wrong property (which will be undefined), you won't be able to find your user later.